# Prove that f is 1 time continuously differentiable and express f' in terms of f

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose that $f$ is a continuous function on R that satisfies
$$f(x) = 5 + 2\int_0^x f(t) \,dt$$
Prove that $f \in C{^1}(\mathbb{R})$ [ aka $f$ is one-time continuously differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ ]

and express $f'$ in terms of $f$. Then find $f$.

Please help! Any hints much appreciated as I have been stuck on this problem for a few days. I know that the fundamental theorem of calculus must come into play but I am confused because of the fact that using the Fund. Theorem will yield $f(x)$ = 5 + 2$f(x)$... I cannot see how I am supposed to go about this problem.

Also this is for my Real Analysis class, so all of our proofs are based from that type of thinking/knowledge base.

Answer (score 1):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus the function
$$x\mapsto\int_a^x f(t)dt$$
is $C^1$ and it's derivative is $f(x)$ hence by differentiating the given equality we find
$$f'(x)=2f(x)$$
and by solving the above ODE we find
$$f(x)=\lambda e^{2x}$$
but since
$$f(0)=5$$ we have
$$f(x)=5e^{2x}$$ which's a function of class $C^\infty$.

**Edit:** Here we explain the implication: $(f'(x)=2f(x)\Rightarrow f(x)=\lambda e^{2x})$
so let 
$$g(x)=f(x)e^{-2x}$$
so we differentiate $g$ and we have
$$g'(x)=f'(x)e^{-2x}-2f(x)e^{-2x}=2f(x)e^{-2x}-2f(x)e^{-2x}=0$$
hence $g$ is constant say $\lambda$ and then $f(x)=\lambda e^{2x}$.

Comment: unfortunately my class does not use Differential Equations as a prerequisite and this rationalization wouldn't make sense for our purposes

Comment: My answer follows your question: " express $f′$ in terms of $f$. Then find $f$" so just forget the word ODE.

Comment: I am unsure how you got to an exponential function? We always keep the general form of the function

Comment: I edited my answer.